# How to handle a dropdown under an iframe in playwright with Javasvript

Tags: javascript, dropdown, frame, playwright

I have a scenario where I have to access a dropdown and select an option and this dropdown is under a frame
Using playwright with Javasvript

I tried with below code:

```
const frame = await this.page.frameLocator('//iframe[@id="manageCollab"]').locator('//select[contains(@class, "dds__dropdown__input-field")]');

await frame.click();

console.log("Entered dropdown");

const frame2= await frame.getByText('2.External Users');

await frame2.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the select element from the frame.
You can use css to get the frame id using #manageCollab and the select element using css class attribute .dds__dropdown__input-field :)

```
const selectElement = await this.page.frameLocator('#manageCollab').locator('.dds__dropdown__input-field');
```

Then assuming 2.External Users is a label of an option in the select element

```
await selectElement.selectOption({ label: '2.External Users' });
```

Or if it is the option value

```
await selectElement.selectOption('2.External Users');
```

Comment: I tried with the above also but still not able to even access the dropdown. 
Gives the same error: Unknown engine “internal:control” while parsing selector

Comment: @ShiviBhatnagar Try using playwright codegen and see what it generates for you.
Use this on cmdline: npx playwright codegen https://yoururl

Comment: I tried with codegen also: It generates await this.page.framework(#manageCollab).locator(‘select’).selectOption(‘2.Extrenal Users’);  and this gives me the same error

Comment: @ShiviBhatnagar This is now sounding more like the installed playwright version has perhaps got corrupt.  When I get things like this, I usually end up nuking playwright and then installing a later version.  I have had to do this twice in the last year or so and both times my issue was solved.  Certainly worth a try and it is quick to do.